# Reverse diagonalLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am currently working on Oracle's example class, [DiagonalLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CustomLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/DiagonalLayout.java).

This class creates a diagonal layout (left to right). I would reverse the direction (right to left) by selecting a JCheckBox.

How?

Comment: this is my actual GUI:
http://i639.photobucket.com/albums/uu116/wadjo/diagonalLayout.png

Answer (score 3):

`DiagonalLayout` has a fixed behavior of laying out components from left to right.

In order to get components in reverse diagonal order, you would have to develop your own `ReverseDiagonalLayout` with the required `layoutContainer` implementation. The original layout can serve as guide however.

Comment: I'm not expert in java, can you please help me to create this layout ?

Comment: This is a non-trivial task and will take time if you decide to take this route. Here is [more info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/howLayoutWorks.html). If there is an off-the-shelf one available it would be preferable to use that.

Comment: @wadjo What a better way then to get more experience of Java then trying your own hand.  You already have an implementation that does left-right as bases